# How can I render "uneven" tuplets in ABC notation?

Tags: tuplet, abc-notation

I understand how to create "normal" tuplets in ABC: for example, where a triplet contains three notes, or a quintuplet contains five notes.

```
X:1
T:"Normal" Tuplets
M:2/4
L:1/16
K:none
(3A2A2A2 (5AAAAA
```

But I can't figure out how to do it if I want, say, a triplet with a quarter-note and an eighth note. Can ABC do that? How should it be coded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is explained in the [tuplets section](http://abcnotation.com/wiki/abc:standard:v2.1#duplets_triplets_quadruplets_etc) of the ABC standard.

To code tuplets with multiple note-lengths, use the *p:q:r* notation.

> More general tuplets can be specified using the syntax (p:q:r which means 'put p notes into the time of q for the next r notes'.

To render a triplet comprising a quarter-note (crotchet) and an eighth-note (quaver), you would write (3:2:2. [Note the use of the abbreviation (3::2 in the third triplet.]

This code...

```
X:1
T:Tuplets Example
M:3/4
L:1/8
K:none
(3:2:2 A2A (3:2:2 A2A (3::2 A2A
```

...renders this result...

```
X:1
T:Tuplets Example
M:3/4
L:1/8
K:none
(3:2:2 A2A (3:2:2 A2A (3::2 A2A
```